# 301 Redirect appending filename to new URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to create Apache 301 redirect in htaccess file, from static html page to new dynamic wordpress page:

> **old**: example.com/category/item.html
>
> **new**: example/newpage

Redirects without category are working fine, like:

> **old**: example.com/item.html
>
> **new**: example/newpage

But with category, every redirects I tried ended up adding item.html at the end of URL:

> example.com/newpage/item.html

I tried these redirections:

```
Redirect 301 /category/item.html http://example.com/newpage
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/category/item.html$

RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where are you doing the redirect?  Can you show us what code is performing the redirect??

Comment: Thanks for answer, I added the codes I tried, any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
RewriteRule ^category/item\.html$ /newpage? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with simple **Redirect 301** in right order:

```
Redirect 301 /category/oldpage.html /newpage
Redirect 301 /category /newpage
```

I was using it in wrong priority, so it didn't work at first. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

When redirection in .htaccess does not work for me, I use jQuery. If you have conflict puts the jQuery in a `file.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="https://example.com/category/item.html"]').each(function() {
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("https://example.com/category/item.html", "https://example/newpage"); // Create new url

        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
    });
});
</script>
```